# Connect SharePoint 2010 date filter web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer, filter, calendar

I have used the date filter web parts to filter the SharePoint list.

1. Here filter is getting applied on change of date.. Can we add a button and run the filters only on button click?
2. Can we change the calendar format (I mean look and feel)?

Thanks..